# Possible to use LESS to access value of selected element's existing attributes?

Tags: less, stylesheet, mixins, css

I have a class defined in my LESS partial:

```
.myclass
{
    border-radius: [CALCULATION: e.g. this.height + 2px];
}
```

I'd like to calculate the border-radius based upon the element's height (as seen in the syntactically-incorrect example above).

**What I've Tried**

I have a work around:

```
.myclass(@height)
{
    border-radius: @height + 2px;
}
```

The problem with the above is that `myclass` may be a div with a content manageable area inside of it (so the div could well grow to an arbitrary height), so I can't necessarily pass the height as a parameter to a mixin.

NOTE: I've also tried percentages, but the border radius looks skewed.

I don't want to use any javascript for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using javascript this is not possible as your less will be pre-compiled into standard css.

If you are happy to use javascript and less.js you could use `less.modifyVars()` ([link to docs](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser-modify-variables)).